# standardized header library for financial time series data in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, finance

I'm new to Pandas, and I'm trying to import financial time series from various csv sources into Pandas. However all of the csvs have different headers, which means I currently need to build custom logic to deal with each one. I'm wondering if there might be a library or other utility available to get them into a standardized format.

For example, a time series from one vendor might use `"Trade Date"` vs another that uses `"Date"` or `"TradeDate"`. Also, the date format within this column varies between sources, so I need to handle that. Similarly, `"Open"`, `"OpenPx"`, and `"Open Price"` are all the same thing.

Finally, some csvs have non-useful text in the first or last line such as `"This data is the property of ..."`, that I'd like to automatically remove.

Currently I'm using `df = pandas.read_csv()` to read in the non-standardized data, and then clunky code to remove the unnecessary top text and change header names into a single standardized set. I'd like something more graceful / easier to maintain, if it exists.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: read_csv has a lot of args to help with this kind of stuff. Think it may help to give some examples of what you're looking at... (I was thinking about guessing it's a date from col title the other day, read_json does it - I think it's a good soln)

Comment: Thanks Andy, I hadn't noticed read_csv's args; parse_dates is definitely cleaner than what I was doing, as are index_col and dtype. I guess what I'm hoping for (which I probably didn't say clearly) is a maintained library that knows how to clean up / standardize the data given its source. E.g. for a CSV from Yahoo Finance do x to clean it, from CFE do y to clean it.

Comment: You might like to check out pandas.io.data http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/remote_data.html. Not sure I can point you to another library, possible you can do some generic stuff with pandas relatively easily... but I think you'll need some explicit examples for us to help!

Comment: Andy you've opened my eyes to a far better way of getting the data: directly without the intermediate csv step. Thank you! 
I have 4 main sources for my data: Yahoo Finance, Google Finance, IB, and CBOE/CFE. The first two are covered by the remote_data you mentioned, and google has yielded some promising starting points for the other two, for example https://github.com/blampe/IbPy for IB, and http://code.google.com/p/trading-with-python/source/browse/trunk/cookbook/downloadVixFutures.py for CBOE.
I'll still need some manipulation to get them into a standardized format but it's looking easier!